# Deleting EKS Cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, load-balancing, amazon-eks

I am trying to delete my cluster for two days now. I am still unable to do that. It gives me the following error whenever I try to delete the cluster.

```
cannot delete orphan ELB Security Groups: cannot delete security group k8s-elb-aca08d9bf0d2411eab4930a519e18ad2: DependencyViolation: resource sg-0ac89a5984f250d5b has a dependent object
    status code: 400, request id: ce0efc48-14cd-4cba-ae2c-98467c3bde20
```

The problem is finding what that dependent object. I have gone through the documentation but and googled it as well. I have read that it can have something to do with ENIs and instances. but I check all the ENIs as well. and I am unable to delete my ENIs too. It gives me the error, that it is already in use. Please help me because it's costing me a lot of money every single day.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to delete the ELB manually:

```
aws elb delete-load-balancer --load-balancer-name <load-balancer-name>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue with ENI being attached to the security group.

First find the eni that is attached with the subnet in error i.e, sg-0ac89a5984f250d5b in this case.

Go to ENI and detach/delete the respective ENI

Comeback and delete the respective security group.

Now you can try deleting the node-group and it will get deleted